# Firebase PhoneAuthentication working in debug build but not working in the release build

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on implementing the newly released firebase phone authentication in my app. The problem is when I debug through the android studio, I receive the SMS OTP. But when I install the release application, the OTP does not arrive. It has happened with multiple devices all who worked while debugging. Here's the code for phone authentication activity

```
package com.icucs.ip;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseTooManyRequestsException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class PhoneAuth extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private boolean mVerificationInProgress = false;
    private String mVerificationId;
    private static final int STATE_INITIALIZED = 1;
    private static final int STATE_CODE_SENT = 2;
    private static final int STATE_VERIFY_FAILED = 3;
    private static final int STATE_VERIFY_SUCCESS = 4;
    private static final int STATE_SIGNIN_FAILED = 5;
    private static final int STATE_SIGNIN_SUCCESS = 6;
    private Button mStartButton;
    private Button mVerifyButton;
    private Button mResendButton;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private EditText mPhoneNumberField;
    private EditText mVerificationField;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private static final String TAG = "PhoneAuthActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_auth);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(PhoneAuth.this, MainActivity.class));
                }
            }
        };

        mStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_start_verification);
        mVerifyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_verify_phone);
        mResendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_resend);
        mPhoneNumberField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_phone_number);
        mVerificationField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_verification_code);

        mStartButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mVerifyButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mResendButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Phone Authentication
        mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
                // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
                // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
                //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
                // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
                //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verificaiton without
                //     user action.
                Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + credential);
                // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                mVerificationInProgress = false;
                // [END_EXCLUDE]

                // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                // Update the UI and attempt sign in with the phone credential
                updateUI(STATE_VERIFY_SUCCESS, credential);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
                // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.
                Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e);
                // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                mVerificationInProgress = false;
                // [END_EXCLUDE]

                if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                    // Invalid request
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    mPhoneNumberField.setError("Invalid phone number");
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                    // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Quota exceeded.",
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }

                // Show a message and update the UI
                updateUI(STATE_VERIFY_FAILED);
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }

            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                                   PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
                // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
                // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
                // by combining the code with a verification ID.
                Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:" + verificationId);

                // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
                mVerificationId = verificationId;
                mResendToken = token;

                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                // Update UI
                updateUI(STATE_CODE_SENT);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        if (mVerificationInProgress && validatePhoneNumber()) {
            startPhoneNumberVerification(mPhoneNumberField.getText().toString());
        }
    }

    private void startPhoneNumberVerification(String phoneNumber) {
        // [START start_phone_auth]
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
                120,                 // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
        // [END start_phone_auth]

        mVerificationInProgress = true;
    }

    private void verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(String verificationId, String code) {
        // [START verify_with_code]
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
        // [END verify_with_code]
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
    }

    // [START resend_verification]
    private void resendVerificationCode(String phoneNumber,
                                        PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
                60,                 // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                mCallbacks,         // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                token);             // ForceResendingToken from callbacks
    }
    // [END resend_verification]

    // [START sign_in_with_phone]
    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");

                            FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                            // [START_EXCLUDE]
                            updateUI(STATE_SIGNIN_SUCCESS, user);
                            // [END_EXCLUDE]
                        } else {
                            // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                // The verification code entered was invalid
                                // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                                mVerificationField.setError("Invalid code.");
                                // [END_EXCLUDE]
                            }
                            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                            // Update UI
                            updateUI(STATE_SIGNIN_FAILED);
                            // [END_EXCLUDE]
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private boolean validatePhoneNumber() {
        String phoneNumber = mPhoneNumberField.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber) || phoneNumber.length() > 10 || phoneNumber.length() < 10) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Enter valid phone number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mPhoneNumberField.setError("Invalid phone number.");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void updateUI(int uiState) {
        updateUI(uiState, mAuth.getCurrentUser(), null);
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        if (user != null) {
            updateUI(STATE_SIGNIN_SUCCESS, user);
        } else {
            updateUI(STATE_INITIALIZED);
        }
    }

    private void updateUI(int uiState, FirebaseUser user) {
        updateUI(uiState, user, null);
    }

    private void updateUI(int uiState, PhoneAuthCredential cred) {
        updateUI(uiState, null, cred);
    }

    private void updateUI(int uiState, FirebaseUser user, PhoneAuthCredential cred) {
        switch (uiState) {
            case STATE_INITIALIZED:
                // Initialized state, show only the phone number field and start button
                enableViews(mStartButton, mPhoneNumberField);
                disableViews(mVerifyButton, mResendButton, mVerificationField);
                break;
            case STATE_CODE_SENT:
                // Code sent state, show the verification field, the
                enableViews(mVerifyButton, mResendButton, mPhoneNumberField, mVerificationField);
                disableViews(mStartButton);
                break;
            case STATE_VERIFY_FAILED:
                // Verification has failed, show all options
                enableViews(mStartButton, mVerifyButton, mResendButton, mPhoneNumberField,
                        mVerificationField);
                break;
            case STATE_VERIFY_SUCCESS:
                // Verification has succeeded, proceed to firebase sign in
                disableViews(mStartButton, mVerifyButton, mResendButton, mPhoneNumberField,
                        mVerificationField);

                // Set the verification text based on the credential
                if (cred != null) {
                    if (cred.getSmsCode() != null) {
                        mVerificationField.setText(cred.getSmsCode());
                    } else {
                        mVerificationField.setText(R.string.instant_validation);
                    }
                }

                break;
            case STATE_SIGNIN_FAILED:
                Toast.makeText(this,"Sign In failed\nTry Again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case STATE_SIGNIN_SUCCESS:
                startActivity(new Intent(PhoneAuth.this,MainActivity.class));
                break;
        }

        if (user == null) {
            //Signout options
        } else {
            //Signed in
        }
    }

    private void enableViews(View... views) {
        for (View v : views) {
            v.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private void disableViews(View... views) {
        for (View v : views) {
            v.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_start_verification:
                if (!validatePhoneNumber()) {
                    return;
                }

                startPhoneNumberVerification(mPhoneNumberField.getText().toString());
                break;
            case R.id.button_verify_phone:
                String code = mVerificationField.getText().toString();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(code)) {
                    mVerificationField.setError("Cannot be empty.");
                    return;
                }

                verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(mVerificationId, code);
                break;
            case R.id.button_resend:
                resendVerificationCode(mPhoneNumberField.getText().toString(), mResendToken);
                Log.d("Chekc","asd");
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the SHA-1 of your release APK to the Firebase console for that project?

Comment: I am seeing similar issue.  without SHA-1, it has error about not being able to send OTP code.  I added SHA-1 and still not receiving OTP.  I no longer see error message either,  how can we debug on where the error is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certain Google Play services (such as Phone Auth ,Google Sign-in and App Invites) require you to provide the SHA-1 of your signing certificate so we can create an OAuth2 client and API key for your app. To get your SHA-1, follow these instructions:
Open a terminal and run the keytool utility provided with Java to get the SHA-1 fingerprint of the certificate. You should get both the release and debug certificate fingerprints.
To get the release certificate fingerprint:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias <your-key-name> -keystore <path-to-production-keystore>
```

set your app's SHA-1 hash in the Firebase console

Also, note that phone number sign-in requires a physical device and won't work on an emulator.

Comment: After executing errror appears: `keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Only one command is allowed: both -exportcert and -list were specified.`